# Blue/Green deployment with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a blue-green deployment setup in our infra (quick info - a new server/container is started with new build; traffic is moved to these new servers in rolling manner; 1 down from old set, 1 up from new one).
Problem is, at one point there could be a scenario that traffic is served from both (old/new) deployments. The JS for one deployment may not be available on the other.

In request tab of console, I can see that requests for chunk is in the form of `domain.com/_nuxt/<component>/<part><hash>.js`. While in build folder of nuxt, component exist in form of `<component>_<part><hash>.js`.

Will it be safe to sync the generated js files to s3, and serve them via a static hosting (e.g AWS-S3), and create a proxy server on Nginx for rerouting part. I couldn't find any existing solution for this.

Most of the solutions describe how to do the deployment with zero downtime, and suggests approaches around changing the directory via soft-links, to handle zero downtime. It doesn't solve the case, where a user might already be on the website, and not necessarily has explored all the pages of webapp (so all js file are loaded).

Comment: You can store old chunks for last 1-2 deployments too.  And in nuxt 2.4 default behaviour for missing chunks would be automatic reload of page

Comment: is it safe to serve `_nuxt/*` via the above mentioned routing?

Comment: Im not quite understand. <component>/<part><hash>.js - this shouldnt happen

Comment: Check this site for example https://www.gamevix.com/ (Network tab request - `_nuxt/pages/news.d4619c07d2bed3d1170e.js`). with the same name there must be a file in build folder `pages_news.d4619c07d2bed3d1170e.js`

Comment: its not default behaviour for sure. u have something customized in your config. Or you have some old version of nuxt..

Comment: This is the behavior on Windows system. On Linux, the dist folder has the correct directory structure.

Comment: I use Windows and never had this. If h can create a reproduction repo with steps it would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

It is safe for the JS and assets files as long as your S3 has all the files for all the deployment. However, you must make sure that all the files are inside S3 before the switch happens.

The only concerns are your API, service, business logic. During the switch, you must not deploy conflicting API versions.

- Green: `example.com/v1.0/data`, returns an Array
- Blue: `example.com/v1.0/data`, returns an Object

During the switch, your Green code might call the Blue code and due to the different response structure, your Green Vue code is not prepared to handle the new data structure.

You can mitigate this by properly upgrading your API versions.

Have multiple API versions `example.com/v1.0/data` and `example.com/v1.1/data`. During the deployment, your Blue/Green will get routed to the respective APIs. It's pretty tedious.

I talked about it briefly using AWS Rolling Updates: [AWS Nuxt Zero Downtime](https://medium.com/@fuxingloh/nuxt-js-aws-zero-downtime-deployment-fa5248f5ff51)